# ¿Cómo conectar varios RFIDs en Arduino?

Tags: arduino

Buenas mi problema no es el cableado. Si no en la parte del código de los RFIDs. El proyecto lo que tiene que hacer cuando pase una tarjeta (cualquiera de los RFIDs) que tengo registrada lo muestre por pantalla. Si no esta registrada sonará un buzzer. Pues **mi problema es que solo me funciona un RFID el otro no** .Os dejo el código que he hecho

```
#include <SPI.h> //Serial Peripheral Interface. Es una libreria regula diversos protocolos de comunicacion de varios dispositivos integrados
#include <MFRC522.h> //Libreria del RFID
#include "EasyBuzzer.h" //Libreria del Buzzer

const byte pinBuzzer = 6;

//Configuracion del sonido del Buzzer
unsigned int frequency = 1000;
unsigned int onDuration = 50;
unsigned int offDuration = 100;
unsigned int beeps = 2;
unsigned int pauseDuration = 500;
unsigned int cycles = 10;

#define NR_OF_READERS   2

//Pines de los RFIDS
#define RST_PIN         9          //RST -> Reset 
#define SS_PIN_rfid1    10         //SS -> Slave Select es una variable sirve para el intercambio de datos
#define SS_PIN_rfid2    7
//Vector donde almacenamos los pines de cada RFID
byte ssPins[] = {SS_PIN_rfid1, SS_PIN_rfid2};

byte LecturaUID[4];         // crea array para almacenar el UID leido
byte uidLlaveroRegistrado [4] = {0x6A, 0x5B, 0x35, 0x16}; //Diferentes uids de los llaveros y tarjetas

// Create an MFRC522 instance :
MFRC522 mfrc522[NR_OF_READERS];

void setup() {

  EasyBuzzer.beep(
    frequency,    // Frequency in hertz(HZ).
    onDuration,   // On Duration in milliseconds(ms).
    offDuration,  // Off Duration in milliseconds(ms).
    beeps,      // The number of beeps per cycle.
    pauseDuration,  // Pause duration.
    cycles     // The number of cycle.
  );

  Serial.begin(9600);       // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  while (!Serial);      // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
  SPI.begin();          // Init SPI bus
  //Aquí iniciamos los diferentes RFIDS
  for (uint8_t reader = 0; reader < NR_OF_READERS; reader++) {
    mfrc522[reader].PCD_Init(ssPins[reader], RST_PIN); // Init MFRC522
    mfrc522[reader].PCD_DumpVersionToSerial();  // Show details of PCD - MFRC522 Card Reader details
  }
  //COSA IMP
  //PCD -> Proximity Coupling Device en otras palabras es el lector del RFID vamos la cosa azul
  //PICC -> Proximity Integrated Circuit Chip y esto es la tarjeta blanca NO LOS LLAVEROS
  delay(4); // Optional delay. Some board do need more time after init to be ready, see Readme
}

void loop() {
  for(uint8_t reader = 0;reader < NR_OF_READERS; reader++) {
    // Reset the loop if no new card present on the sensor/reader. This saves the entire process when idle.
    if ( ! mfrc522[reader].PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) { //Aqui buscaremos si hay tarjetas comunicando desde el propio lector -> PICC_IsNewCardPresent()
      return;
    }

    // Select one of the cards
    if ( ! mfrc522[reader].PICC_ReadCardSerial()) { //Si la tarjeta contiene algún tipo de dato -> PICC_ReadCardSerial()
      return;
    }
    // Dump debug info about the card; PICC_HaltA() is automatically called
    //mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));

    //En este Bloque de codigo nos mostrara por la terminal de Arduno el UID de la tarjeta
    Serial.print("UID:");       // muestra texto UID:
    for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522[reader].uid.size; i++) { // bucle recorre de a un byte por vez el UID
      if (mfrc522[reader].uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10) {  // si el byte leido es menor a 0x10
        Serial.print(" 0");     // imprime espacio en blanco y numero cero
      } else {         // sino
        Serial.print(" ");      // imprime un espacio en blanco
      }
      Serial.print(mfrc522[reader].uid.uidByte[i], HEX);  // imprime el byte del UID leido en hexadecimal
      LecturaUID[i] = mfrc522[reader].uid.uidByte[i];   // almacena en array el byte del UID leido
    }
    Serial.print("\n");

    if (comparaUID(LecturaUID, uidLlaveroRegistrado)) { //En caso que este registrado
      Serial.print("Que tal Hijo de Puta \n");
    } else {  //En caso que no este registrado
      buzzer();
    }
    //Paramos la comunicacion con las tarjetas
    mfrc522[reader].PICC_HaltA();      // detiene comunicacion con tarjeta
  }
}

//Esta funcion compara el uid extraido con el registrado dentro del sistema
//Devuelve TRUE si esta dentro del sistema
//FALSE en caso contrario
boolean comparaUID(byte lectura[], byte usuario[]) {
  for (uint8_t reader = 0; reader < NR_OF_READERS; reader++) {  //Aqui accedemos a todas las tarjetas
    for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522[reader].uid.size; i++) {   //Aqui buscamos el uid de la tarjeta
      if (lectura[i] != usuario[i]) {
        return (false);
      }
    }
  }
  return (true); // si los 4 bytes coinciden retorna verdadero
}

void buzzer() {
  analogWrite(pinBuzzer, OUTPUT);
  /* Always call this function in the loop for EasyBuzzer to work. */
  EasyBuzzer.update(); //Hay que ponerlo siempre
}
```

Me he dado cuenta que mi problema debe de estar en la primera linea del "void loop" Ya que si cambio "reader" de 0 a 1. Me funcionará el otro RFID y viceversa. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Me parece que debes usar "menor que" en lugar de "menor o igual" en `for(uint8_t reader = 0;reader <= NR_OF_READERS; reader++)`

Comment: Si antes lo tenía así pero me daba el mismo problema

Comment: Estás intentando acceder al tercer elemento de un arreglo que sólo tiene dos elementos. Ese es un error de todas maneras

Comment: De todos modos estaba ahora debugeando y me he dado cuenta que poniendo debajo del for un "print(reader)" solo me imprime el 0 en ningún momento el 1, es decir, que el bucle no esta iterando no se pq. Tengo el mismo código que el de la pregunta.

Comment: Fijate que sales de "for" si el primer RFID no está disponible, y nunca miras el segundo RFID por tanto

Comment: Muchas gracias era esa tonteria